# Can I install Ubuntu on this SSD?

Tags: installation, windows-8

I reseted my Windows 8 notebook (Lenovo U410) and reinstalled. Now W8 is installed on my C drive and nothing is on my 24 GB SSD. That mean that SSD is free and I can use it for Ubuntu install? I don't wanna mess my notebook and I want to dualboot Ubuntu and Windows.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install Ubuntu on your SSD and enable trim support after install by clicking here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/enable-trim-on-ssd-solid-state-drives.html

Comment: Ok, so if I install Ubuntu on my SSD, I can boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu? Will that mess my Windows 8 install? I've heard about problems with GRUB...

Comment: Here's an easy guide to help: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html